# cut and paste issue with sublime text ST3

Tags: sublimetext3

a recent problem has occurred in Sublime Text 3.  Ctrl-x no longer cuts the selection, unless I press it twice.  However, that just seems to delete it as the clipboard is just empty for pasting.

I have performed a search of the packages folder and then the entire sublime text folder for ctrl-x to see if I could spot anything stealing the shortcut but have not spotted anything. Any suggestions?

Whilst I can copy, delete, then paste I have 20 or more years of programming finger memory here which is hard to override.

**Additional info:**

I have since found out ctrl-x twice does cut, but ctrl-v does a cut and paste (this cut removing whatever was in the clipboard).  It seems that there is also an error in the gitgutter plugin so I am removing that and working from there)

**Fixed**
Turned out to be the origami plugin. Thanks

Comment: when you say you have searched for `ctrl-x`, do you mean that literally?  the way keybindings work, you should search for `ctrl+x` to find if anything is overriding the default binding.

Comment: Sorry i meant ctrl+x

Comment: if you run the following in Sublime's python console, what happens? does it work as expected? `sublime.active_window().active_view().run_command('cut')`

Comment: Yes it cuts - I am monitoring the actions in the console now and ctrl-v both cuts and pastes.

Comment: If I cut with the mouse, then ctrl-v works.  If I ctrl-x ctrl-x    to cut with the keyboard, ctrl-v pastes empty

Comment: it might be worth disabling all packages and then checking what happens.  If everything works properly with no enabled plugins, then enable one at a time and test again, and when it stops working, you will know which is causing the strange behavior.

Comment: Yer I was reaching that conclusion too. Thanks for your input

Comment: Did that, at last, turned out to be the origami plugin. all working fine